# React Native Animated.event() inside a function

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to animate some components on scroll, using
`const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;` for tracking the value.

This code below works:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: scrollY,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }
  )}
></Animated.ScrollView>;
```

But I want to be able to  extract `Animated.event` function within the `onScroll` prop to its own independent function. This code below doesnt seem to update scrollY:

```
// My onScroll handler
const handleScroll = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
  // Some other code here...

  return Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: scrollY,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }
  );
};

// Scrollview component
<Animated.ScrollView onScroll={handleScroll}></Animated.ScrollView>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured it out, but this will work:

```
  const handleScroll =
        scrollY && (() => {
            console.log('hey');

            return Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }], {
                useNativeDriver: true,
            });
        }
        )();
```